# CSS blur effect is different on Chromium(brave) browser

Tags: html, css, user-interface, chromium, brave

I was trying to use a blur effect on a `radial-gradient` background, The result is the same in all browsers except Chromium(brave), I also tested on windows

> Opera 80.0.4170.63 Linux

> [image]

> Brave 1.31.87 Linux | Chromium 95.0.4638.54 Linux

> [image]

Code:

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(red, white);
  filter: blur(254px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

I first tested on brave and then realize it's the same issue on chromium since brave is using it. This is not the case on Firefox, Chrome and Opera.

There is not different vendors for brave or chromium to change the CSS style, How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check if it's available to use "radial-gradient" in specific browsers on this website .
https://caniuse.com/?search=radial-gradient

Comment: The brave browser is using chromium version 95, It is available.

Comment: @Silent-B So if it's true there could be a solution to change gradient rules for browsers , where it's necessary. I think it's due different render in some browsers.